# How can I resolve 'failed to fetch extensions. XHR Failed' error in VScode when trying to add extensions?

Tags: xmlhttprequest

When I first download VScode and try to add extensions I get an error saying "failed to fetch extensions. XHR Failed." Can anyone help me resolve this?

I tried to change some JSON settings, nothing worked. Perhaps I did it wrong.